# Convert only named HTML entities to XML valid numeric entities?

Tags: javascript, web

I'm trying to parse a XML on the browser but always get the error 'Entity 'nbsp' not defined' (and others). I understand this is because this XML is bad formed since named entities usually supported on HTML aren't valid in XML (besides a few selected).

How can I fix this XML and make it valid for parsing? I checked the robust [he](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/he) library but it seems the only way I would be able to do this is to decode and then encode but then all XML breaks since <> would be converted.

Is there any better, more robust alternative to just doing a search & replace of the named entities I can remember?

Also tried the jQuery trick of `$('<textarea />').html(data).text()` but then I get some invalid `&` present on my code that I need to reencode. I'm just trying to build a robust solution that works in all cases because the XML inputs would be varied and... wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

I want to precede this with: "I haven't tried this in Javascript", but I have tried this with *other* valid XML parsers.

The thing about entities in XML is, you can define your own and you can define their meaning.

For instance, you can define the entity `&hello;` with:

```
 <!ENTITY hello "Hello world!">
```

It's also possible to import a list of entities from an external DTD file.

So you should be able to import the XHTML entity DTD and get replacements:

https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml-lat1.ent (note: this link is slow, make a local copy)

And you should be able to import it by placing this at the top of your XML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE foo SYSTEM "xhtml-lat1.ent">
```

Note that its been years since I've tried this so I couldn't tell you 100% sure if this syntax is correct or if the standard Javascript XML parser will support this.

**edit** this works in firefox:

```js
const xml = `<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE foo [<!ENTITY hello "hello world">]>
<hi>&hello;</hi>`;

const parser = new DOMParser();
const xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xml,"text/xml");
console.log(xmlDoc.childNodes[1].textContent); // "hello world"
```